# Проход for или foreach по полям объекта JavaScript (по возвращаемому JSON объекту result.d)

Tags: json, asp.net-webforms, javascript

На ajax запрос приходит ответ от ASP.NET формируемый следующим образом:

```
Dictionary<String, String> features = new Dictionary<String, String>();
foreach (AttributeValue attribute in queryResult.First()) {
    features.Add(attribute.Name, attribute.Value.ToString());
}
```

Обращаться к полям результата по имени не с руки

```
...
result.d.name
result.d.code
result.d.index
...
```

т.к. число полей и их набор не всегда известны заранее.

Вопрос: можно ли for или foreach пройтись по полям ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно использовать `for in`

```
for(var key in result.d)
{
     console.log(result.d[key]);
}
```

или использовать `Object.keys()`

```
var keys = Object.keys(result.d)
for(var i = keys.length; i--; )
{
    console.log(result.d[keys[i]]);
}
```

- **[Цикл for in](http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#object.forinloop)**
- **[Object.keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff688127(v=vs.94).aspx)**